# Trying to make message randomizer with parts PYTHON

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, message

So this bot is telegram bot, which sends people a message after random intervals.

What I want to create is a code, which will put together full message from randomly chosen message segments.

So here is the message from the code:
`messages= ["Hey I'm new to software trading, how has Ainstein been performing for you? Any problems you have encountered?"]`

Right now its just 1 message, but what I want to do, is cut this message into 3 segments.

**Example:**

Segment1 = "Hey I'm new to software trading"

Segment2 = ", how has Ainstein been performing for you? "

Segment3 = "Any problems you have encountered?"

**But what I want to do is that the message will be put together from segments like message = Segment1 + Segment2 + Segment3**

**But what I want to do is that every Segment will have 3 different possbilities.**

Like this:

Segment1:

a1 = "Hey I'm new to software trading"

a2 = "Hello I'm new to software trading"

a3 = "Hi I'm new to software trading"

Segment2:

b1 = ", how has Ainstein been performing for you? "

b2 = ", how has Ainstein been working for you? "

b3 = ", how has Ainstein performed for you? "

Segment3:

c1 = "Any problems you have encountered?"

c2 = "Any errors you have had?"

c2 = "Any problems you have had?"

And basically what I want to do is that these a1-a3 & b1-b3 & c1-c3 will randomize itself every loop.

**So like message the full message will be randomized between a1-a3 + b1-b3 + c1-c3**

So it could print for one user:

a1 + b2 + c3 = Hey I'm new to software trading, how has Ainstein been working for you? Any problems you have had?

or

a2 + b1 + c1 = Hello I'm new to software trading, how has Ainstein been performing for you? Any problems you have encountered?

So i hope you guys get the point :) Hope someone can help, its probably easy fix for advanced programmers, im just very new to python.

I'm very new to Python, so I have not find a solution online & cannot figure it out myself..

Here is my full code:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError
import sys
import csv
import random
import time
from numpy.random import default_rng
from time import sleep

api_id = 1234567   #Enter Your 7 Digit Telegram API ID.
api_hash = 'hash'   #Enter Yor 32 Character API Hash.
phone = 'phonenumber'   #Enter Your Mobilr Number With Country Code.
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

rng = default_rng()

SLEEP_TIME_2 = 100
SLEEP_TIME_1 = 40
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))

users = []
with open(r"Scrapped.csv", encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    next(rows, None)
    for row in rows:
        user = {}
        user['username'] = row[0]
        user['id'] = int(row[1])
        user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
        user['name'] = row[3]
        users.append(user)

mode = int(input("Enter 1 to send by user ID or 2 to send by username: "))

#Enter you message here!
messages= ["Hey I'm new to software trading, how has Ainstein been performing for you? Any problems you have encountered?"]
for user in users:
    if mode == 2:
        if user['username'] == "":
            continue
        receiver = client.get_input_entity(user['username'])
    elif mode == 1:
        receiver = InputPeerUser(user['id'],user['access_hash'])
    else:
        print("Invalid Mode. Exiting.")
        client.disconnect()
        sys.exit()
    message = random.choice(messages)
    try:
        SLEEP_TIME = rng.uniform(37, 67)
        print("Sending Message to:", user['name'])
        client.send_message(receiver, message.format(user['name']))
        print("Waiting {} seconds".format(SLEEP_TIME))
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    except PeerFloodError:
        print("Getting Flood Error from telegram. Script is stopping now. Please try again after some time.")
        print("Waiting {} seconds".format(SLEEP_TIME_2))
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_2)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        print("Trying to continue...")
        print("Waiting {} seconds".format(SLEEP_TIME_1))
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_1)
client.disconnect()
print("Done. Message sent to all users.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [random.choice](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choice.asp) function to get a random item from the list:

```
from random import choice

def get_random_string():
    s1 = [
        "Hey I'm new to software trading", 
        "Hello I'm new to software trading", 
        "Hi I'm new to software trading"]
    s2 = [
        ", how has Ainstein been performing for you? ", 
        ", how has Ainstein been working for you? ", 
        ", how has Ainstein performed for you? "]
    s3 = [
        "Any problems you have encountered?", 
        "Any errors you have had?", 
        "Any problems you have had?"
    ]
    return choice(s1) + choice(s2) + choice(s3) 

...

message = get_random_string()
print(message)
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the wisdom & time buddy!!! I tryed to add it to the code, but got an error, so I have must done somehting wrong.

Could you show exactly where I should paste it in my code, so its correct? :)

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: it just sent "," to the first user & i stopped.

Maybe you can copy my code from the post & place that code you made in it correctly? So i know its perfect :) Thanks a lot if you can!!!

Comment: If your code was working before, you just need to replace `message = random.choice(messages)` with `message = get_random_string()` and add function and import above

Comment: Yeah I tryed exactly that, but then it just printed with my code a coma to the telegram chat, not a sentence. So it just sent ","

Thats why i ask maybe you can just place it in my code & send me the full code? :D

Comment: oh i see i will try, i just changed the upper messages= with that, maybe thats the issue

Comment: BRO THANKS SO MUCH!!! I GOT IT WORKING!
I just deleted the messages= & added what you said! fantastic!